# How can I improve the performace of my UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a `UITableView` which loads images from a firebase database. Each cell in the table contains three pictures. The firestore query loads three documents at a time, while the table view paginates when the users scroll to the bottom. The issue I am having is that as I scroll the table view stutters every time it reaches a new cell. Each cell takes up a little more than the full screen. Here is an example of what I am trying to describe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WytOd.jpg

Here is the code that is producing these issues:

```swift
func paginate(){
    postQuery = postQuery.start(afterDocument: documents.last!)
    self.loadPosts()
}

//queries Firestore and loads into postArray
func loadPosts() {
    if let blockedArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: blockKey) as? [String]{
        blockedUsers = blockedArray
    }
    postQuery.getDocuments{ [weak self](querySnapshot, error) in
        self!.q.async{
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }else{
                var postsTemp = self?.postArray
                for doc in querySnapshot!.documents{
                    self?.documents += [doc]
                    let post = self!.createPost(doc)
                    if(!self!.postArray.contains(post) && !self!.blockedUsers.contains(post.uid)){
                        postsTemp?.append(post)
                    }
                     
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self!.postArray = postsTemp!
                        self!.tableView.reloadData()
                        self!.isNewDataLoading = false
                    }
                }
                self!.loadedFirst = true
            }
        }
    }
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if postArray.count == 0{
        return 1
    }else{
        return postArray.count
    }
}
   
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var post: PostStruct
    var peopleUserIsFollowing: [String] = []
        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.delegate = self
    if postArray.count == 0 {
        let instructions = cell.textLabel
        instructions?.text = "Press the camera to start Piking!"
        instructions?.textAlignment = .center
        clearPosts(cell)
    }else {
        post = postArray[indexPath.row]
        if let leftPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbLeftKey) as? [String]{
           votedLeftPosts = leftPostArray
        }
        if let rightPostArray = userDefaults.array(forKey: fbRightKey) as? [String]{
            votedRightPosts = rightPostArray
        }
            
        let firstReference = storageRef.child(post.firstImageUrl)
        let secondReference = storageRef.child(post.secondImageUrl)
            
        //For FriendsTableView query
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let followingReference = db.collection("following")
            .document(currentUser!)
            .collection("UserIsFollowing")
        followingReference.getDocuments(){(querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    peopleUserIsFollowing.append(document.documentID)
                }
            }
        }
            
        //Fill in labels and imageViews
            
        cell.timer = createTimer(post, cell)
            
        cell.firstImageView.sd_setImage(with: firstReference)
        cell.secondImageView.sd_setImage(with: secondReference)
            
        cell.leftTitle.text = post.firstTitle
        cell.rightTitle.text = post.secondTitle
            
        cell.postDescription.text = post.postDescription + "\(indexPath)"
        if post.userPic == "" {
            userPic =
                    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pikit-7e40e4.appspot.com/o/Default%20Profile%20Pic.png?alt=media&token=2bc88382-2ad3-4eb8-8163-dcddf391c666"
        } else{
            userPic = post.userPic
        }
        let url = URL(string: userPic)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) 
        cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            
        let votesCollection = db.collection("votes").document(post.postID)
        getCount(ref: votesCollection, cell: cell)
            
        if(post.uid != currentUser){
            cell.userName.text = post.poster
        }else{
            cell.userName.text = "Me"
            cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = false
            cell.tapRight.isEnabled = false
        }
        cell.textLabel?.text = ""
            
        if(post.poster == Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid || post.endDate - Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970) <= 0){
            cell.tapRight.isEnabled = false
            cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = false
            cell.firstImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            cell.secondImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
        else if(votedRightPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
            cell.secondImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            cell.secondImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
            cell.firstImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            cell.tapRight.isEnabled = false
            cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = true
        }
        else if (votedLeftPosts.contains(post.firstImageUrl)){
            cell.firstImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            cell.firstImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4
              
            cell.secondImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0
            cell.tapLeft.isEnabled = false
            cell.tapRight.isEnabled = true
        }
            
    }
        
    return cell
}
    
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let postCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    clearPosts(postCell)
    postCell.timer?.invalidate()
    postCell.timer = nil
}
    
    
    
override func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    //Bottom Refresh
        
    if scrollView == tableView{
            
        if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
        {
            if !isNewDataLoading{
                isNewDataLoading = true
                paginate()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried adjusting what `didEndDisplaying` does, such as clearing cells/ not clearing cells, but that had no effect. I have also tried changing around where paginate is called but this seems to be the best way. I am not sure where I went wrong. I have also noticed in the Xcode debugger that the memory usage of the app steadily rises as the table view is scrolled up and down, but never seems to go down.

Comment: Do not use scrollview for pagination, use tableview methods end display cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you have two options to fix this problem.  That's a lot of code to parse through, so I can't give you a code sample, but the answers are either:

**Pre-fetching**

When you scroll to item 2, kick off the fetch for items 4,5,6 (since you fetch 3 at a time) before you scroll down that far.

Also... you might consider fetching more than 3 at a time. Like... 50, or 100.  Modern iOS devices have lots of memory.  No real reason I can think of to limit it to so few.

**Placeholders**

Build your layout so it gives placeholder data and then kick off the fetch asynchronously to update the on-screen layout with the real data.

Either way is going to require you to restructure your code a bit.  My intuition says that pre-fetching is going to be easier for you.